# No Performance gain after using OpenMP to optimize loop

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to optimize a for loops which loops 1 million times and add two arrays with `pow` in use. My system is having 48 cores. I have used malloc to get the arrays and using pragmas from pthread created by a main process. Unfortunately the parallel version of the code is taking almost 20 times more time than the serial version(in the same system). I am using `gettimeofday` to check the execution time. My gcc version is 4.3.4. Please help me understanding and fixing this.

My code:

```
#define N 1000000
#define CHUNKSIZE 20833
:
:
double                          *a, *b, *c;
struct timeval                  st, et;
long double                     time_used[48], tot_time;
:
:
a = malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
b = malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
c = malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
     a[i] = b[i] = i * 1.0;
chunk = CHUNKSIZE;
:
:
#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,chunk,time_used) private(i)
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        gettimeofday(&st, NULL);
        long double st_in_micro = (st.tv_sec)*1000000 + (st.tv_usec); 
        #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic,chunk) nowait
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
            c[i] = a[i]*pow(2,2) + b[i]*pow(3,2);

        gettimeofday(&et, NULL);
        long double et_in_micro = (et.tv_sec)*1000000 + (et.tv_usec);
        time_used[tid] = et_in_micro - st_in_micro;
        printf ("time taken by thread %d = %Lf\n", tid, time_used[tid]);
    }

    tot_time = 0;
    for (i=0; i<48; i++)
    {
        if (time_used[i] < 0)
            continue;
        tot_time += time_used[i];
    }
    printf("Total time taken by all the threads = %Lf\n", tot_time);
```

Output of Parallel version:

```
time taken by thread 20 = 936.000000
time taken by thread 35 = 1826.000000
time taken by thread 17 = 2.000000
time taken by thread 38 = 603.000000
time taken by thread 22 = 2009.000000
time taken by thread 43 = 0.000000
time taken by thread 13 = 1703.000000
time taken by thread 14 = 1750.000000
time taken by thread 31 = 2128.000000
time taken by thread 1 = 2298.000000
time taken by thread 47 = 602.000000
time taken by thread 34 = 1749.000000
time taken by thread 7 = 1642.000000
time taken by thread 15 = 2542.000000
time taken by thread 9 = 2628.000000
time taken by thread 42 = 3294.000000
time taken by thread 12 = 3446.000000
time taken by thread 30 = 2290.000000
time taken by thread 23 = 3711.000000
time taken by thread 5 = 0.000000
time taken by thread 4 = 2457.000000
time taken by thread 16 = 2573.000000
time taken by thread 6 = 2715.000000
time taken by thread 41 = 2456.000000
time taken by thread 2 = 2877.000000
time taken by thread 0 = 2721.000000
time taken by thread 26 = 4209.000000
time taken by thread 37 = 2796.000000
time taken by thread 24 = 2846.000000
time taken by thread 46 = 2999.000000
time taken by thread 39 = 2569.000000
time taken by thread 45 = 2128.000000
time taken by thread 29 = 2855.000000
time taken by thread 44 = 3075.000000
time taken by thread 36 = 1.000000
time taken by thread 32 = 3035.000000
time taken by thread 3 = 1544.000000
time taken by thread 27 = 3132.000000
time taken by thread 25 = 3076.000000
time taken by thread 33 = 1.000000
time taken by thread 28 = 3042.000000
time taken by thread 21 = 3237.000000
time taken by thread 19 = 1594.000000
time taken by thread 18 = 2202.000000
time taken by thread 10 = 1655.000000
time taken by thread 8 = 3931.000000
time taken by thread 40 = 2726.000000
time taken by thread 11 = 2060.000000
Total time taken by all the threads = 105671.000000
```

Output of Serial version:

```
Total time taken by all the threads = 5574.000000
```

Please help me to understand what is wrong with this code.

Comment: To begin with, `c` is probably not actually allocated until `for (i=0; i<N; i++) c[i] = ...` which will screw up the benchmarking. To avoid this, initialize it so something.

Comment: The most glaring issue is the rase condition on `et` and `st` - these variables *must* be private. Why would use use dynamic loop scheduling for such a regular workload. And why such an odd chunksize? If you improve on that, provide a [mcve] as well as a specific system configuration (CPUs, Memory, compiler options, OpenMP settings / environment variables)

Comment: @Zulan, 1000000/48

Comment: I agree that I should have declare `et` and `st` as private. Will try with that but not sure if that will help. Only compiler option I used was `-fopenmp`, nothing else. No environment variables are set. As Zulan said, chunksize is taken as loop_limit/no_of_cores.

Comment: @Lundin, initialising `c` worked to some extent. Thanks for that. But still the parallel version is taking 3 times more time than the serial one. I declared `st` and `et` as private too. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the time used by each thread to `tot_time` and comparing that to the time when only one thread is used.

Doing this `tot_time` for all threads will in most cases ([exception for super linear speedups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup#Super-linear_speedup)) be greater or equal to the time for when only one thread is used. The ideal case is when they are equal that means the time was evenly distributed across all threads.

So your definition of `tot_time` is an interesting metric to test how well the load is distributed but I don't think it is what you are looking for.

Instead you could report the time of the thread that took the maximum time. But only reporting the time used inside the parallel region removes the cost of the overhead of implementing the work sharing by OpenMP.  Instead I would report the time used by the entire work sharing region as in the following code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(double * restrict a, double * restrict b, double * restrict c, int N) {
    double tot_time = -omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        double dtime = -omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) c[i] = a[i]*pow(2,2) + b[i]*pow(3,2);
        dtime += omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp critical
        printf ("time taken by thread %d = %.2f seconds\n", omp_get_thread_num(), dtime);
    }
    tot_time += omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Total time taken by all the threads = %.2f seconds\n", tot_time);
}

int main(void) {
    int N = 1<<28;
    double *a = malloc(sizeof *a * N);
    double *b = malloc(sizeof *b * N);
    double *c = malloc(sizeof *c * N);
    memset(a,1,sizeof *a * N);
    memset(b,1,sizeof *a * N);
    memset(c,1,sizeof *a * N);
    foo(a,b,c,N);
}
```

Your code also had some race conditions which I fixed.

Lastly memory when it's first allocated does not (normally) allocate all the pages until it's first written to. Interesting enough `calloc` does not allocate the pages either and instead just points to a single zero page. Even more complicated is that GCC will convert `malloc` followed by `memset(0)` to `calloc`. So in order to actually allocated the pages you need to write a non-zero value to the array (`.e.g memset(a,1,sizeof *a * N)`).

Here is the result of the timing on my 4 core/8 hardware thread system.

```
time taken by thread 1 = 0.33 seconds
time taken by thread 5 = 0.33 seconds
time taken by thread 7 = 0.33 seconds
time taken by thread 6 = 0.34 seconds
time taken by thread 3 = 0.34 seconds
time taken by thread 4 = 0.34 seconds
time taken by thread 0 = 0.34 seconds
time taken by thread 2 = 0.33 seconds
Total time taken by all the threads = 0.36 seconds
```

Then `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2`

```
time taken by thread 0 = 0.31 seconds
time taken by thread 1 = 0.33 seconds
Total time taken by all the threads = 0.33 seconds
```

Then `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`

```
time taken by thread 0 = 0.53 seconds
Total time taken by all the threads = 0.53 seconds
```

Your operation is memory bandwidth bound so I don't see much benefit after two threads on my dual channel DDR4 system.

---

With NUMA systems memory locality can have a big effect.  Since the pages are only allocated the first time they are touched then for benchmarking it may make sense to write to the arrays in parallel first.  The following code will do this but it only works for static scheduling.

Make sure to disable dynamic adjustment of the number of threads (not to be confused with dynamic scheduling) with e.g. `export OMP_DYNAMIC=false`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(double * restrict a, double * restrict b, double * restrict c, int N) {

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) c[i] = b[i] = a[i] = 1;

    double tot_time = -omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        double dtime = -omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp parallel schedule(static) nowait
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) c[i] = a[i]*pow(2,2) + b[i]*pow(3,2);
        dtime += omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp critical
        printf ("time taken by thread %d = %.2f seconds\n", omp_get_thread_num(), dtime);
    }
    tot_time += omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Total time taken by all the threads = %.2f seconds\n", tot_time);
}

int main(void) {
    int N = 1<<28;
    double *a = malloc(sizeof *a * N);
    double *b = malloc(sizeof *b * N);
    double *c = malloc(sizeof *c * N);
    //memset(a,1,sizeof *a * N);
    //memset(b,1,sizeof *a * N);
    //memset(c,1,sizeof *a * N);    
    foo(a,b,c,N);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That mostly worked for me. But still I have few questions; will be great if you help understanding.  1) In my 48 cores system, I got best result when using 4 to 16 threads. If I go beyond that performance is degrading. results with 1 and 48 threads are almost similar. Why this is like that? 2) Why do we need to call that printf in `critical`? 3) While initializing the arrays why do we need to use only static scheduling?

Comment: @Phaniarnab did you try the 2nd code I added? Instead of using memset it initializes the arrays in parallel. This should improve the data locality.  Please state exactly what your hardware is.  You likely have a a multisocket system. For example two 12 cores processors with hyper-threading. What kind of memory do you have.  How many nodes? How much memory per node? You can use `numactl -H` to get this information.  Also look at `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `sudo dmidecode -t memory`.

Comment: @Z boson, thanks. I could tell you the following information.  1 node of size 524242MB, number of cpus 48. Model is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz with 12 cpu cores per processor. 16 RAMs are installed of 32GB each. I am yet to try your 2nd code.

Comment: @Phaniarnab. You must have a dual socket system. Each socket has 12 cores/24 hardware threads. You need to try the second code because it should allocated the memory local to each socket. The first code allocates the memory local to one socket so memory accesses from the second socket are slow.